# Survey migration from SP 2010 to SP Online thru Sharegate

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-online

We are migrating Survey lists from SP 2010 to SP Online , and we observed that all responses with 'Completed' Status as 'No' in SP 2010 have changed to 'Yes' in SP Online after migration even though the survey was not completed.

Does Sharegate not retains the state of the responses after migration ?

Thanks

Comment: Can anyone please help to answer this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you contact support@share-gate.com, they'll need your Migration Report to help you investigate your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mia, yes i contacted them and they have asked for the migration report to investigate the same, as it is not a normal behavior. Thanks